# JavaScriptSerializer deserialize multiple JSON arrays in single string

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, serialization

In short, I have a client Windows Forms app that receives a Json string from an API in the following form:

```
string textResult = "{"Data":[{"ID":"G0000013","M_CurBalanceOutstanding":52408.5}],"DataDetail":[{"ErrorDate":"\/Date(1410179960809+0200)\/","ErrorID":1,"ErrorInfo":"Success"}]}"
```

or formatted via http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "ID": "G0000013",
      "M_CurBalanceOutstanding": 52408.5
    }
  ],
  "DataDetail": [
    {
      "ErrorDate": "/Date(1410164281557+0200)/",
      "ErrorID": 1,
      "ErrorInfo": "Success"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to de-serialize it like this:

```
var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<MatterDetailBalOutstanding> results = deserializer.Deserialize<List<MatterDetailBalOutstanding>>(textResult);
```

**where textresult is my JSon string.**

I have the following classes:

```
[DataContract]
    class MatterDetailBalOutstanding
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal M_CurBalanceOutstanding { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<MatterReturnStatusDetails> ErrorData;

        public MatterDetailBalOutstanding(string _ID, decimal _M_CurBalanceOutstanding, List<MatterReturnStatusDetails> _ErrorData)
        {
            ID = _ID;
            M_CurBalanceOutstanding = _M_CurBalanceOutstanding;
            ErrorData = _ErrorData;
        }
    }
```

and:

```
[DataContract]
    class MatterReturnStatusDetails
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Info { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public MatterReturnStatusDetails(int _ID, string _Info, DateTime _Date)
        {
            ID = _ID;
            Info = _Info;
            Date = _Date;
        }
    }
```

I just cannot get it to work? To my understanding it is possible to de-serialize a string containing two JSon arrays. I have read a ton of threads, and a lot of them suggest using another serializer. I have to go with JavaScriptSerializer though. Please could someone help with this? What am I doing wrong? Where am I missing something?

**Update 1:**

When I try:

```
MatterDetailBalOutstanding results = deserializer.Deserialize<MatterDetailBalOutstanding>(textResult);
```

I get the below error:

No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'ConsumeTestWCFApp.ConsumeTestWCFApp+MatterDetailBalOutstanding'.

Comment: How is the serializer supposed to map an object with a member named `Data` to a `List`? You need an object which has a member named `Data`. In other words, you class structure must match the data structure (or be annotated to match it)

Comment: @DarkFalcon, you pointed me in the right direction, thank you. Can't believe I overlooked something like this. Make sense. Will mark up your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to assist you in generating classes suitable for mapping your JSON. Here is the result :

```
public class Datum
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double M_CurBalanceOutstanding { get; set; }
}

public class DataDetail
{
    public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }
    public int ErrorID { get; set; }
    public string ErrorInfo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public List<DataDetail> DataDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can annotate and modify the generated classes further as necessary and use it in deserialization :

```
var result = deserializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(textResult);
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. Useful little tool json2csharp will definitely remember in future. Thanks to you and @DarkFalcon. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem:

> No parameterless constructor defined for type of
>   'ConsumeTestWCFApp.ConsumeTestWCFApp+MatterDetailBalOutstanding'.

occurs because your serialized classes do not have a default constructor. By creating a specific constructor like this:

```
class MatterDetailBalOutstanding
{
    public MatterDetailBalOutstanding(string _ID, decimal _M_CurBalanceOutstanding, List<MatterReturnStatusDetails> _ErrorData)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

you do not get a default constructor and have to add one yourself:

```
class MatterDetailBalOutstanding
{
    public MatterDetailBalOutstanding(string _ID, decimal _M_CurBalanceOutstanding, List<MatterReturnStatusDetails> _ErrorData)
    {
      ...
    }

    public MatterDetailBalOutstanding()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

This may not be you biggest problem now, but I didn't see anyone answer that part of the question.